# ubuntu + hhvm results in my tmpfs is full - 100% used

Tags: ubuntu, hhvm

Ubuntu 14.04, HHVM 3.10.1

Running `df -h` I can see the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G  8.0K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.6G  8.0K 100% /run
/dev/xvda1      9.8G  2.1G  7.2G  23% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

What's taking up the full space in tmpfs is actually the file `/run/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc` which is 1.6 GB currently. Is this healthy? It does not look like it is.

I have found the following, related to the full tmpfs:
https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/issues/132

> "On my Ubuntu (14.04) /var/run is a tmpfs mount that's only 400MB in
>   size. The hhvm.hhbc file grew to a little over 350MB on one system. I
>   think it may make more sense to default to putting this file under
>   /var/cache/hhvm instead."

My central path is just as explained, defined to /var/**run**/hhvm/hhvm.hhbc - but i do not have a /var/**cache**/ in my filesystem, so i wonder if i really should change the central path to /var/cache/hhvm instead? Also, wouldn't this be bad / not be temporary since tmpfs is mounted to only /run?

I am debugging since my HHVM is crashing periodically, which requires that i run a reboot of hhvm service/remove the hhvm.hhbc before everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

The hhvm.hhbc file is the hiphop compiled bytecode. From the looks of it, it's getting too big for your tmpfs. You can either change the path to somewhere on /dev/xvda1, or increase the size of your tmpfs partition (if your memory allows for it)

Using the tmpfs path is fast, since the compiled code repo will be read from memory, setting it to an actual on disk file system will slow down the reads.

Comment: What causes the hhvm.hhbc to get bigger and bigger? Seems like there is no limit. If it will stop somewhere in size, how will i determine this size without going to increase > crash > increase > crash to find out the size. Also how can i increase the tmpfs partition? isn't it automatically set